# Adding GPS tracking data from Excel into QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps

I have added GPS points in QGIS however all of them are the same colour. I want the points to be coloured differently for each individual.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rightclick on the layer -> Properties, Style tab

Change the dropdownbox from `Single Style` to `Categorized`. Choose a column, then click on `Classify`, then `Ok`.